# How to add a default value to a kubernetes helm template

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

If I have a basic kubernetes helm template like below:

```
port: {{ .Values.Port }}
```

Is there a way to specify a default port if none is passed in?

Answer (score 26):

In `values.yaml` you put `Port: <port-number>` which will be used if you don't pass the value using `--set`.

You can also set default like following

```
port: {{ default 1234 .Values.Port }}
# You can replace 1234 with your port number
```

Answer (score 18):

The designated place for default values according to the [Helm documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines/#using-the-default-function) is the [values.yaml](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/values_files/). This is where to look first to peruse the default configuration of a Chart. Also, it can be overwritten if need be by providing a customized values.yaml from the command line.

Also, there is the [default template function](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines/#using-the-default-function). The intention here is usage for computed default values, e.g.:

```
drink: {{ .Values.favorite.drink | default (printf "%s-tea" (include "fullname" .)) }}
```